# Orchard CMS: ContentPart not added to ContentItem in migration

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to build a module with the following in a migration:

```
    public class XyzzyPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual string Plugh { get; set; }
    }

    public class XyzzyPart : ContentPart<XyzzyPartRecord>
    {
        public string Plugh {
            get { return Retrieve( r => r.Plugh ); }
            set { Store( r => r.Plugh, value ); }
        }
    }

    public int Create() {

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable( "XyzzyPartRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column<string>( "Plugh" )
        );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition( "XyzzyPart", cfg => cfg
            .WithDescription( "XyzzyPart" ) );

        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition( "XyzzyItem", cfg => cfg
            .WithPart( "XyzzyPart" )
        );

        return 1;
    }
```

When accessing an XyzzyItem, there is no XyzzyPart in the Parts collection. Instead there is a ContentPart.

How do I get my Content Part to allow it to be added to a Content Item's Parts collection?

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to create items of that type you just created, before the migration is done running. In general, migrations are not the right place to create contents. Recipes are where this should be done.

Comment: I edited the question to better reflect the issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had neglected to create either a Driver or a Handler for my part. Once those were in place my code worked as expected.

```
namespace MyProject.Drivers {

    public class XyzzyPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<XyzzyPart> {

        protected override DriverResult Display( XyzzyPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper ) {
            return ContentShape( "Parts_Xyzzy",
                () => shapeHelper.Parts_Xyzzy(
                    Xyzzy: part ) );
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProject.Handlers {

    public class XyzzyPartHandler : ContentHandler {

        public XyzzyPartHandler( IRepository<XyzzyPartRecord> repository ) {
            Filters.Add( StorageFilter.For( repository ) );
        }
    }
}
```